# Set printing settings programmatically for chart control (mscharts)

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

Is there a way to programmatically set some of the settings for the chart printing?  I want the default print orientation to be landscape, but the only way I can find to do that is launch the `chart1.Printing.PageSetup()` and have the user do it.  I'd prefer to handle it all myself in code.

Below are my options.  I tried playing with the `PrintDocument` settings, but couldn't find what I needed.

[image: Options]

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0 and I'm using winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set all kinds of properties, pretty much as you tried to do. Just look a little closer into the various properties of the [`PrintDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx), which is a regular `PrintDocument` object!

The `Orientation` is hidden behind the `Landscape` property..:

```
 chart1.Printing.PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```

Comment: Ah, I must have skimmed over it.  Thanks!